# Error: Auto count the adding of textbox which is not supposed to be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I'm an adding a textbox, the main textbox auto input the number of textbox has been added which is not totally needed.

Here's the codes

```js
function addElement() {
  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
  var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value - 1 + 2);
  numi.value = num;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var divIdName = 'my' + num + 'Div';
  newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);
  newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"> <label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left"></p></label> <div class="col-xs-7">  <input type=text id=' + num + 'value= ' + num + ' class= "req"><a href="javascript:remove(' + divIdName + ')">Remove</a>';
  ni.appendChild(newdiv);
}


function remove(dId) {
  var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  ni.removeChild(dId);
}
```

```html
<label for="color" class="control-label col-xs-4">
  <p class="left">Color/s</p>
</label>


<input name="color" class="req" id="theValue" autocomplete="off" required/>

<p><a class="btn btn-default bt " role="button" href="javascript:addElement()">Add Color</a>
</p>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
```

Comment: `(document.getElementById('theValue').value - 1 + 2);` why not just use Number() or parseInt() to convert it to a number?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:remove(myNaNDiv)">Remove</a>`

Comment: @epascarello can you show me how? and where will I put the <a href="javascript:remove(myNaNDiv)">Remove</a>

Comment: That is what your code generates....That is your problem.

Comment: the remove button is now working, but there some other error, please check my updated question and try run the code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you adding the textbox try the different differnt value in first textbox it will work. issue is you entered 1 and click the "Add Color" it will create new div as my2Div, again you clicked the "Add Color" so again it will create new div with same id my2Div. and then if you click to remove, then we have two div with same id "my2Div" so it will throw error.

First entered 1 then click on **Add Color** i will create text box, then entered 2 in first text box then click on Add Color it will again create the new Div with different id this time you can use your remove fuctionality.

I will say the add logic is not correct.

try the below [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfh765uw/)

```
var numi = document.getElementsByName('theValue');
var num = (numi.length + 1);
..
..
newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);
newdiv.setAttribute('name', 'theValue');
```

Comment: but really i didn't get what you wrote in your code.. if there any relation with the first textbox? i  just provide you a sample you can modify as per your business scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the ID as an argument, you need to get the actual DOM element to be able to remove it.

```
    function remove(dId) {
       var parentNode = document.getElementById('myDiv'), 
       childNode =document.getElementById(dId) ;

       parentNode.removeChild(childNode);
    }
```